# наследование ООП

Tags: c++, ооп

У меня есть класс `Tree` и класс `Node`. В `Node` будет несколько переменных, мне нужно чтобы переменная из класса `Tree` была общей для всех детей, я хотел сделать `static`, но тогда я не могу ее инициализировать в `tree`. Какой лучший способ это сделать?

Comment: Если у вас есть эти классы, будьте добры, скопируйте их в вопрос(определения не нужны)

Comment: Вы уверены, что она действительно нужна в каждом Node? Если вы всегда посещаете любой Node, зная какое из деревьев обходите, то очевидно, что эта переменная программно доступна.

Comment: Кто кого наследует, какая переменная должна быть общей и для "детей" какого класса?... ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Общей для всех потомков делает переменную не модификатор ***static***, а модификатор ***protected***.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node {
  Tree *tree;
  ...
```

Comment: и  наверное со спецификатором доступа  protected